# Export "tab" table from Stata to Latex

Tags: tables, stata

I would like to transfer a table that I've created with the "tab" command in Stata directly to Latex. In other cases, I've used the esttab and estout commands (and I've read a number of other stack exchange posts that use these commands), but it seems there should be a simpler way to export something generated via the "tab" command directly. I want a table with number of observations in each category, i.e. I have the following

```
tab age educ
```

which generates the following in Stata

[image]

and I'd like to export this directly to Latex. What are some options?

Comment: please show the daa as a text block as it is exported, not as an image

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean? My question is how to export it

Comment: well that is a stata question so off topic here and most of us won't have that software so couldn't really help anyway) But I assumed that it was generating a text file with that table as "ascii art" and you are showing a screen dump,  latex could input the text and if you posted an example, someone could test some code to do so. But with an image not really anything we can say. unless you just want to include th image in laex with `\includegraphics` ?